# Limit range for the Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a method in Google API V3 by which I can set my map to show up in certain range only and not go beyond that, also the autocomplete option show the suggestion within those coordinates ?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://jrochelly.com/post/2014/03/save-google-maps-waypoints/) shows how to save a route with multiple waypoints. But in the second code snippet there is a function to limit the map boundaries, so when you drag the map outside of the limits, it returns to the boundaries you´ve defined.

The relevant code is in lines 35 to 56 of the seconde code block.

As from the autocomplete, you can only set it to a default region. To do so, you add "&region=XY" to the script src tag.